# How to Avoid Launching the Android Application Twice ,Running from Eclipse to real device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, main-activity

I am Running the application from eclipse and it's being launched twice: first time launching the app, then again relaunching after few seconds

My app **Splash Screen--->> Main activity**(Both Opening twice).

i already tried adding  **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** in my manifest file, but not success.

i have tried 3 different applications from my eclipse still opening twice in my **Kitkat ,lollipop real device** (created new project that one also opening twice)

**EDIT 1 :**

Tried adding  this line in manifest file but not Success-**android:launchMode="singleTop"**

please let me know How to solve this issue.

manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >


        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

My start Activity.java

```
public class Start extends Activity
{


        SessionManagerFor_Signin session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManagerFor_Signin(getApplicationContext());

         // Remove the Title Bar
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);


        ImageView Image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        //Animation Bottom to Top        
        TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,400.0f, 0.0f); 

            animation2.setDuration(1000);  
            animation2.setFillAfter(false); 
            Image1.startAnimation(animation2);


        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {

        @Override
        public void run()

        {
            try {
                sleep(3000);


            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();    

            }
            finally
            {
                session.checkLogin();
                finish();

            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();


    //For Full Action bar Color Starts
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                setTranslucentStatus(true);
            }

            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintResource(R.color.FUllStartColor);

    //For Full Action bar Color Ends here           
}
    @TargetApi(19) 
    private void setTranslucentStatus(boolean on) {
        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }
```

Comment: i have tried 3 different applications from my eclipse still opening twice in my real device Kitkat ,lollipop(also created new project that one also opening twice)

Comment: Have you got any solution? I'm also facing same issue. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding launchMode "singleTop" in your Manifest to your activity.

```
<activity
  android:name="MyActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
  ... >
```

Answer (score 2):

**Remove this** from one of the two activities:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This intent-filter indicates to Android which is the Main Activity, and you should have one only.

Comment: i have tried 3 different applications from my eclipse still opening twice in my real device Kitkat ,lollipop(also created new project that one also opening twice) but working good in jellybean device.

Answer (score 2):

Apply intent filter only in one of your activity. Remove from MainActivity...

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >


        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you please post your start activity code snippet

Comment: i added my start activity

Comment: this might be a eclipse issue?

Comment: ya i tried 3 applications opening 2 times why? running from eclipse to real device

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

May be this will work.
If it does not work then reinstall eclipse.

Comment: i want to reinstall the eclipse or Sdk?

Answer (score 0):

**Apply** the below to your splash screen activity,then clean the project and run again..

Try to register activity in manifest file with complete package name.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: this might be a Eclipse issue?

Comment: Have u checked in in real device ??

Comment: ya i have tested in real device, twice opening